# Is it possible to install a bathroom fan, vanity power plugs, LED lights, a small towel dryer and a smart toilet on just 2 circuits?

Tags: electrical, bathroom

I have this small toilet and I am surprised that it requires its own circuit
https://www.ovedecors.com/en/stan-toilet.html

```
    POWER OUTLET REQUIREMENT
This  product  must  be  plugged  into  a  working  GFCI  power  outlet  to  avoid  potential  damages  on  the  electronic 
component during electrical surges. The power outlet must have a dedicated minimum 1800W capacity for the 
smart toilet.
```

I currently have a GFCI power outlet that is used for the vanity
It needs to be relocated but the current position would allow me to split and reach both the new position and the smart toilet

The other circuit supports LED lights and the fun,
Not sure where to place the small towel dryer (probably on the lights/fun circuit??

Would these work ? Both are 15 AMP circuits

Answer (score 2):

### You can share GFCI receptacles. You might have to.

OK. Here's a science fact you do not know, and neither do the people who wrote that instruction.

A GFCI is not a receptacle.   It is a *system of protection* that can protect any number of outlets.  In fact they make GFCIs that are not receptacles - GFCI only, or GFCI+breaker, or GFCI+switch.

Anyway, every GFCI device can protect other equipment that is wired downline of it... it has a set of terminals called "Load" which are for exactly that purpose **and no other purpose**.

Now, obviously, a GFCI *receptacle* protects *its own sockets* but it still has those "Load" terminals that you're not supposed to use for anything else.

So GFCIs have 4 screws - 2 Line and 2 Load.  Unfortunately, plain old receptacles have 4 screws. So when novices upgrade receptacles to GFCI, they just go "la la la, 4 screws = 4 screws done!". So they are *accidentally* putting the downline on the "Load" terminals, giving it protection *they don't even realize*.

Those instructions are written for novices, and so they told you it needs to be a GFCI receptacle.  **It does not:** a plain receptacle *fed from the "Load" terminals of an existing GFCI receptacle* is perfectly fine for that requirement.

So you do not need to relocate the vanity GFCI for this purpose alone: you can simply feed off its "Load" terminals to grant GFCI protection to any other plain outlets in this same bathroom.

In fact, you may be *required* to: Code does not like GFCI receptacle in inaccessible locations, because it's too difficult to do the monthly required test.

### However, the bidet requires a dedicated circuit

It's right there in the instructions, which you must follow (NEC 110.3(B)).

So that means your only wiring option is 1 circuit dedicated to the bidet, and the other circuit used for all other loads.

### Bathroom receptacle circuits must be 20A

Keep in mind *if this is NEW wiring*, bathroom receptacle circuits must be 20A. All of them.  You cannot use a 15A MWBC (shared neutral) as a substitute (though a 20A MWBC would certainly do the trick).

If you cannot meet the "accessible GFCI" requirement, you can fit a GFCI *deadfront* (which is a device that is GFCI only) at an accessible location.

Really, the correct way to wire an outlet for a dedicated circuit is to use a 1-socket receptacle.  Those are not made in GFCI (except for GFCI+outlet+switch combo device) and so again, the deadfront might be the way to go.

Comment: It isn't just because it says "use dedicated". It also says 1800W, which I suspect is because of the "Integrated hot water heating system", which effectively means "nothing else on the same circuit".

Comment: The GFCI protected outlet that is on its own circuit is o the opposite wall so yes I can use the load wires to feed the bidet. Questuon is can I put the fan the lights and the power pkug for the vanity and the towel dryer on the same curcuit?

Comment: @manassehkatz  I dont see why I cant have the  vanity plugs on the same circuit. Nobody can be on the toilet and at the vanity at the same time

Comment: In addition to the installation instructions indicating a **dedicated** circuit, there is a separate rule (not just for bathrooms) that if you have > 50% of a circuit capacity hard-wired then you can't have ordinary receptacles on the same circuit. Assuming the 1800W usage is correct, with a 15A circuit you're done, and with a 20A circuit you could have lights and a simple (i.e., fan only, no heat) fan but probably not much else and not any regular receptacles. Technically, if the toilet is plug-in rather than hard-wired, this may not apply. **But "dedicated" still would apply.**

Comment: @MiniMe Because the bidet might use power at other times than when it is being used, or 2 people might be in the bathroom at once.  Regardless there has to be a safety standard somewhere, or fire insurers won't be able to refuse payment for dangerously done work.  That is established by UL certifying the appliances and NEC regulating installations.

Comment: Then I guess I can put the fan the LED lights the power plug for vanity and the towel dryer on the same circuit and leave the toilet alone. It is a plug in toilet as you can see in the instructions

Comment: Just make 100% certain that the toilet is GFCI protected (whether via receptacle or breaker). Because otherwise a failure would be a true PitA.

Comment: A water heater, towel heater, and ceiling fan .... if you add a hair dryer you could possibly trip TWO 20A circuits.  As long as you're putting cables in the wall of this room why not put in 3 circuits total and make it possible for the person at the vanity to use a hair dryer while everything else is also running?

Comment: @jay613 towel heaters tend to be pretty low power, and so are fans.  A hair dryer could fit on that side, by the skin of its teeth.  But you are right, OP is pretty much expecting electricity to be magic, and is not provisioning capacity to satisfy the considerable  appetite for gadgets.